# How can I throw exception inside a Generic Type Method?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, generics

Is there any way to throw or even safely return an exception inside a generic method?

my sample code looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> findAverage<T>(float a, float b) where T : new ()
{
    try
    {
       ..... Do averaging instructions here......
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       throw e   
    }
}
```

Now it seems good but the problem is whenever I create some test classes, I mean literally separate projects to test, the error redirects to the main source code of the created library. So I thought is there any way to return any exceptions without being redirected to the main library source?

any help || ideas || simple answers would be great. thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Also, never use `throw e;`, use `throw;` instead.

Comment: I'd say that generics have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I was creating a very simple library, and that is the simple in the nutshell code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, unless there is a clear need to do so, it is often better not to catch/re-throw exceptions at this low level of code, instead just let them bubble up to the front end (i.e. either your front end or your test code) for them to handle them as appropriate.

In this case, if you get an exception in your averaging code, what would a reasonable handling of this be? If you are not handling this, then don't catch it at all.